# How to handle null attributes while fetching data from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, aws-lambda-layers, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table where primary key is ID and other attributes are name and balance. Now there are some rows where balance can be NULL. When I am fetching those attributes using Lambda function it cannot handle it. I want to handle these cases so that when a NULL attribute is detected it can show some message.

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = client.Table("demoTable")
    response = table.get_item(
    Key = {
            'ID': '9898'
    }
    
    )
    item = str(response['Item']['balance'])
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in:

`response['Item']['balance']`

Generally, using square brackets to access dictionary members (response is a dictionary) is considered a bad practice. You can use it when you're absolutely sure that the item you're trying to get exists, but a better way is to use `get()` since it can handle situations where the item does not exist.

```
response.get('Item', dictionary()).get('balance', 0)
```

In case the item does not exist, or balance is null, you'll get a 0 as a result